# QGIS 3.4.2 SQL data not displaying on map

Tags: qgis, sql-server, geomedia

When I connect to SQL Server and tick 'Only look in the geometry_columns metadata table' it speeds up the scan but then when I add the feature class to the map it only appears in the layers list and not spatially on the map.

If I don't have this option ticked these features do display on the map, but the scan is much slower. It is not a problem with our cadastral data which we don't create, so I am wondering if the geometry isn't translating properly. We use Geomedia Professional as our GIS which handles geometries differently.

Josh